# How to retrieve list id by list name in Twitter API

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

I've to call this **Twitter** API's method

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/lists/statuses.json?list_id=12345
```

to retrieve the tweets by the user in the list.
But my customer provide me only the name of the list and I've no idea how to get the list id using the list name.
The list is this: `https://twitter.com/DatasportNews/lists/i-campioni-di-brasile2014`.

I've tried with this method

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/lists.json?screen_name=i-campioni-di-brasile2014
```

to get the id list but always return this message

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Your credentials do not allow access to this resource","code":220}]}.
```

I'm logged with api key and api secret and get the token well, but this method doesn't work.

Ideas ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The list name in the URL is referred to as the slug. When you want to request statuses from a list using a `slug`, you simply also need to pass the `owner_screen_name`.

For example, in your case:

`/1.1/lists/statuses.json?slug=i-campioni-di-brasile2014&owner_screen_name=DatasportNews`

More details on this are on the endpoint's doc page at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/lists/statuses